# kudu impala 2.11 hue escape character does not work

Tags: escaping, character, impala, hue, apache-kudu

I use CDH with impala 2.11. 
I have a test table stored in kudu.
I write SQL as follows in HUE:

```
select * from test where name = '\''
```

to find name with only a single quote mark

but it dosen't work.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in hue. I used https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor?editor=93430.
Id/Pass: demo

Please note i used string as column name and hope you are using same. Datatypes like char might also play a role since we are selecting filed explicitly and not checking any field which is having single quote.

[image]

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My test table is store in kudu 1.6. It seems when not stored in kudu , the query works ok.